# How to migrate Files from Godaddy to AWS without FTP

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-web-services, migration, godaddy

Is there any way to migrate files from godaddy server to AWS EC2 without using FTP.

I've tried to migrate using FTP but migration is getting failed. Data is in GBs

Comment: Is this with GoDaddy's cPanel shared hosting?

Comment: Yes! GoDaddy's cPanel - Shared Hosting

Comment: FTP is a fairly well understood technology. It's probably better to get it working properly. SFTP is built into Linux instances, it's part of SSH. Make sure your AWS security group allows your GoDaddy server to access it via SSH, Network ACLs are open, should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sftp`/`rsync`/`scp` from EC2.

See [here](https://godaddy.com/help/connect-to-your-server-or-shared-hosting-account-with-ssh-4943) for the connection info, and [here](https://godaddy.com/help/enable-ssh-4942) for enabling access to SSH.

Comment: Awesome! I researched a bit on the rsync. 
Can you help me with some tutorial? I really don't want to screw up the main site. I would like to keep my second server as a Staging Instance.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend Domain is example.com on Godaddy.

- Login to your GoDaddy account and access cpanel, go to File Manager.
- Compress your website files (all your files in public_html folder).
  Now, your filename is example.com.zip
- Connect to your AWS SSH via Putty or any command terminal. Go to the
  folder of your website using the following command `cd /var/www/`
- `wget http://example.com/example.com.zip` command is to get that zip
  file to your AWS /var/www/ folder.
- `unzip example.com.zip` to unzip all your website files into
  /var/www/ folder.